# Need some advice: saving data to database

Tags: .net, vb.net

[image]

this is roughly the add form where i have created... i am suppose to send this information into the database that i am using which is mysql.
It is suppose to grab the incident date and the Type and also a count that increases by 1 if the date is the same or else it will be back to one.

This is the code

```
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim hotelcode As Integer
        hotelcode = lstHotel.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim objCDBHotel As New CDBHotel
        Dim objCHotel As New CHotel
        Dim hotelname As String
        Dim intNumOfRecordsAffected As Integer

        Dim i As Integer

        If count = 1 Then

            objCHotel = objCDBHotel.getOneHotel(hotelcode)
            hotelname = objCHotel.strHotel
            objCGuestProfile.GuestId = hotelname & " - " & txtIncidentDate.Text & " - " & count
            count = i + 1


        Else

            count = i + 1
            objCHotel = objCDBHotel.getOneHotel(hotelcode)
            hotelname = objCHotel.strHotel
            objCGuestProfile.GuestId = hotelname & " - " & txtIncidentDate.Text & " - " & count

        End If
```

the question is that my count does not increase and also how do i make it check the code and increase by 1 count or change the count back to one if the date is different?
Also how do i remove the slashes in the date so it only takes out the numbers?

Thanks in advance.

@Tim,
 The criteria is the last date used.May i have an example on how to create a if statement with the criteria that is mentioned below?

[if date is used before, the count will +1 else if date haven been used before, it will be 1.]

Also as the "GuestID" will be something like "FHS-201011-1". How do i remove the slashes that has been used in incident date [20/10/11]?

Please advice

Comment: Please copy and paste the code directly inline instead of using an image. Thanks.

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine a date difference?  Is it based on the current date, the last date used, whether or not that date is already in the database, etc?

Comment: You never set count, so it's going to default to 0 and based on your current logic you will always get a value of 1.  You need to determine the criteria for what constitutes a date change and use that criteria in your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Last date used is not necessarily the same thing as date not used before.  You could easily have a date different from the previously used date, but that date was used 3 or 4 entries previously.

I.e., incident date of 01/15/2011.  Last date used was 01/12/2011, but unless you have some other controls/business rules in effect, who's to say that 01/15/2011 wasn't used in a previous incident?

Having said that, let's go with the last date used criteria.

```
' Assumptions:
' 1.  Incident Date is a TextBox with name txtIncidentDate
' 2.  lastDateUsed is a string at the class level that stores the previous value from
'     txtIncidentDate
' 3.  count is an Integer at the class level that holds the current count

'  Here is where you check to see if you need to increment count, or set it back to 1.
If Not txtIncidentDate.Text = lastDateUsed Then
    count = count + 1
Else
    count = 1

objCHotel = objCDBHotel.getOneHotel(hotelcode)
hotelname = objCHotel.strHotel
' Use the String.Replace method to remove the "/"
objCGuestProfile.GuestId = hotelname & " - " & txtIncidentDate.Text.Replace("/", "") & " - " & count

' Update lastDateUsed
lastDateUsed = txtIncidentDate.Text
```

There are some things to consider with the above code snippet:

1. You'll need to validate the format of the value in the Incident Date TextBox.  You might want to convert it to an actual date via [DateTime.Parse Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx), though it looks like you've got a culture-specific format in your app.
2. Trying to reset the count based on a date change in your app without knowing what has been persisted to the database already is likely to cause you grief in the future.  A different approach to consider would be to update the count at the point you insert the data - if you're using a stored procedure for the insert, you could put logic in the procedure to do this.
3. It's not apparent from the code snippet you posted how the actual insert is being made - be **very, very, very, very** leary of taking input straight from the user.  You leave yourself wide open for SQL Injection Attacks.  Use parameterized queries for the actual insert.

Comment: I think if you reread his post he is suposed to send it to the db first then do a simple select count based on date and type which would obviously return total count. That said he does the same thing regardless of what count is so chances are he has misunderstood other aspects of the exercise.

Comment: Hmm....good observation.  If that is indeed the case, it would radically change my answer.